# SQL create weak entity table

Tags: sql, ddl

When I have an entity with another weak entity, how do I create a table in such a situation, where if I delete the primary entity, the weak entity will be deleted as well?

Comment: [cascade delete...?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44956/good-explanation-of-cascade-on-delete-update-behavior) (I think that answer is mysql specific)

Comment: thank you, but would u mind demonstration on how to code it? i am quite confused on it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A foreign key with `on delete cascade` should do the trick:

```
CREATE TABLE primary_entity (
   id numeric PRIMARY KEY,
   -- some data fields
);

CREATE TABLE weak_entity (
   id numeric PRIMARY KEY 
    REFERENCES primary_entity(id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
   -- some data fields
);
```